# 500 internal server error / nginx 1.18.0 while connecting an adonis.js nodejs api backend

Tags: node.js, nginx, adonis.js

I am running a saas platform and sometime we get this error shown in the picture

[image]

`500 internal server error  nginx/1.18.0(ubuntu)` 
but it doesn't happen for everyone.. It happens for some requests.. But if we pm2 reload then it starts working nicely again...

Anyone could advice what could go wrong?

Nginx logs has quite lot of error like this

`*13730731 connect() failed (111: Unknown error) while connecting to upstream, client: 203.45.221.248, server: abc.com, request: "GET /wellness.....`